# ANTLR 4 lexer rule to skip combination of backslash and newline?

Tags: antlr4, lexical-analysis

`WS : [ \t]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs`
Works well to ignore white space by preventing those characters from reaching the parser.  I want to do the same thing with character pair of '/' and newline.  That is, backslash-newline are removed like other white space allowing a single statement to have embedded newlines.

I am trying variations of
`ESC_NEWLINE : '\\'NEWLINE ; NEWLINE :   '\r'? '\n'; WS : ([ \t]+ | ESC_NEWLINE) -> skip ;`  
but this does not skip ESC_NEWLINE.  I don't know what other approach to take.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
ESC_NEWLINE : '\\' NEWLINE;
NEWLINE     : '\r'? '\n';
WS          : ([ \t]+ | ESC_NEWLINE) -> skip;
```

the `WS` rule will never match a `ESC_NEWLINE`. Lexer rules are matched in the following way:

- match as many characters as possible
- if 2 (or more) rules match the same characters, let the rule defined first "win"

This means that the input `\\n` (slash + new line) will always be matched as a `ESC_NEWLINE` rule, never as a `WS` rule.

The solution: let `ESC_NEWLINE` skip itself:

```
ESC_NEWLINE : '\\' '\r'? '\n' -> skip;
WS          : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

Or remove `ESC_NEWLINE`:

```
WS          : ([ \t]+ | '\\' '\r'? '\n') -> skip;
```